# How can I make table for data in Android

Tags: android, datagridview

How can I create a table with borders in **Android**.  table like **data grid view** in .net
or anything like it

Comment: you take a grid view by choosing from layout...

Comment: refer this link http://eclipseandroid.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-display-borders-in-tablelayouts.html table layout with border.

Comment: Look at this [page](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/) (Multi Column ListView)

Comment: you need to use Listview with custom ListView cell go through this tutorial http://ashfaquedl.blogspot.in/search/label/SQLite%20database

Comment: You can also look at http://www.androidjetpack.com/Home/AndroidDataGrid

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example from [android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) that uses `GridView` to display a grid of images

**Layoyt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

**Activity**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**Adapter** (you can modify this class to display any `View` you wish)

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Multicolumn ListView in Android](http://eclipseandroid.blogspot.com/2012/02/multicolumn-listview-in-android.html)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
public class MultiList extends ListActivity {

ListView lv; 
SimpleAdapter sd;
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
   lv=getListView();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> alist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String>map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Date","Date :"+c.get(Calendar.DATE));  // printing date
    map.put("Month", "Month :"+(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)); // printing month
    map.put("Time", "Time :"+new Date().toString());  // printing Date
    alist.add(map);
    sd=new SimpleAdapter(this,alist,R.layout.rows,new String[]{"Date","Month","Time"},new int[]{R.id.t1,R.id.t2,R.id.t3});
    lv.setAdapter(sd);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("Sravan", e.toString());
    }
}
 }
```